# How to access prior rows within a multiindex Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, multi-index

How to reach within a Datetime indexed multilevel Dataframe such as the following: This is downloaded Fin data.
The tough part is getting inside the frame and accessing non adjacent rows of a particular inner level, without specifying explicitly the outer level date, since I have thousands of such rows..

```
                                       ABC        DEF        GHI  \  
Date                STATS                                            
2012-07-19 00:00:00                    NaN         NaN         NaN   
                    investment        4             9          13        
                    price             5             8          1  
                    quantity          12            9          8
```

So the 2 formulas i am searching could be summarized as

```
X(today row) = quantity(prior row)*price(prior row) 
or                           
X(today row) = quantity(prior row)*price(today)
```

The difficulty is how to formulate the access to those rows using numpy or panda for a multilevel index, and the rows are not adjacent.

In the end i would end up with this:

```
                                         ABC        DEF        GHI    XN
Date                STATS                                            
2012-07-19 00:00:00                    NaN         NaN         NaN   
                    investment          4            9          13    X1
                    price               5            8           1   
                    quantity            12           9           8    

2012-07-18 00:00:00                    NaN         NaN         NaN   
                    investment          1             2          3    X2
                    price               2             3          4   
                    quantity           18             6          7    

X1= (18*2)+(6*3)+(7*4) (quantity_day_2 *price_day_2 data) 
or for the other formula
X1= (18*5)+(6*8)+(7*1) (quantity_day_2 *price_day_1 data)
```

Could I use a groupby?

Comment: Can you modify dataframe with small integer values (for easy verifying) and add desired output from sample of data? thanks.

Comment: oh yea ok will do

Comment: Please give me know when question will be changed by comment. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael ok did it.thnks

Comment: One question - what is desired output? 2 new `DataFrame` s?

Comment: Oh desired output could be `inplace=True` or  a second `Dataframe`; it's not so important.thanks

Comment: heyy think i found a small bug in your code. it skips the calculation every 3 or 4 inner lever investment rows. so it computes the col2 value properly 3 or 4 times in a row and then it skips a date, so some investment rows dont have values actually;empty.

Comment: Hmmm, it depends of data. The best is send me some data as csv by email, if not confidental and I test it. If confidental I need sample csv with more data to simulate problem. Maybe problem is in function `shift` is necessary omit `freq`.  Good night. ;-)

Comment: ok sure will do ! good night thaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need add output to original `DataFrame`, then it is more complicated:

```
print (df)
                        ABC  DEF   GHI
Date       STATS                      
2012-07-19              NaN  NaN   NaN
           investment   4.0  9.0  13.0
           price        5.0  8.0   1.0
           quantity    12.0  9.0   8.0
2012-07-18              NaN  NaN   NaN
           investment   1.0  2.0   3.0
           price        2.0  3.0   4.0
           quantity    18.0  6.0   7.0
2012-07-17              NaN  NaN   NaN
           investment   1.0  2.0   3.0
           price        0.0  1.0   4.0
           quantity     5.0  1.0   0.0
```

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

#rename value in level to investment - align data in final concat
idx = pd.IndexSlice
p = df.loc[idx[:,'price'],:].rename(index={'price':'investment'})
q = df.loc[idx[:,'quantity'],:].rename(index={'quantity':'investment'})
print (p)
                       ABC  DEF  GHI
Date       STATS                    
2012-07-17 investment  0.0  1.0  4.0
2012-07-18 investment  2.0  3.0  4.0
2012-07-19 investment  5.0  8.0  1.0

print (q)
                        ABC  DEF  GHI
Date       STATS                     
2012-07-17 investment   5.0  1.0  0.0
2012-07-18 investment  18.0  6.0  7.0
2012-07-19 investment  12.0  9.0  8.0

#multiple and concat to original df
print (p * q)
                        ABC   DEF   GHI
Date       STATS                       
2012-07-17 investment   0.0   1.0   0.0
2012-07-18 investment  36.0  18.0  28.0
2012-07-19 investment  60.0  72.0   8.0
```

```
a = (p * q).sum(axis=1).rename('col1')
print (pd.concat([df, a], axis=1))
                        ABC  DEF   GHI   col1
Date       STATS                             
2012-07-17              NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
           investment   1.0  2.0   3.0    1.0
           price        0.0  1.0   4.0    NaN
           quantity     5.0  1.0   0.0    NaN
2012-07-18              NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
           investment   1.0  2.0   3.0   82.0
           price        2.0  3.0   4.0    NaN
           quantity    18.0  6.0   7.0    NaN
2012-07-19              NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
           investment   4.0  9.0  13.0  140.0
           price        5.0  8.0   1.0    NaN
           quantity    12.0  9.0   8.0    NaN
```

```
#shift with Multiindex - not supported yet - first create Datatimeindex with unstack
#, then shift and last reshape to original by stack

#multiple and concat to original df
print (p.unstack().shift(-1, freq='D').stack() * q)
                        ABC   DEF  GHI
Date       STATS                      
2012-07-16 investment   NaN   NaN  NaN
2012-07-17 investment  10.0   3.0  0.0
2012-07-18 investment  90.0  48.0  7.0
2012-07-19 investment   NaN   NaN  NaN

b = (p.unstack().shift(-1, freq='D').stack() * q).sum(axis=1).rename('col2')
print (pd.concat([df, b], axis=1))
                        ABC  DEF   GHI   col2
Date       STATS                             
2012-07-16 investment   NaN  NaN   NaN    0.0
2012-07-17              NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
           investment   1.0  2.0   3.0   13.0
           price        0.0  1.0   4.0    NaN
           quantity     5.0  1.0   0.0    NaN
2012-07-18              NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
           investment   1.0  2.0   3.0  145.0
           price        2.0  3.0   4.0    NaN
           quantity    18.0  6.0   7.0    NaN
2012-07-19              NaN  NaN   NaN    NaN
           investment   4.0  9.0  13.0    0.0
           price        5.0  8.0   1.0    NaN
           quantity    12.0  9.0   8.0    NaN
```

Comment: Please check my solution - output are 2 dataframes - for 1.st an 2. condion.

Comment: Do you use `(pd.concat([df, b], axis=1)).to_csv()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#add new datetime with data for better testing
print (df)
                        ABC  DEF   GHI
Date       STATS                      
2012-07-19              NaN  NaN   NaN
           investment   4.0  9.0  13.0
           price        5.0  8.0   1.0
           quantity    12.0  9.0   8.0
2012-07-18              NaN  NaN   NaN
           investment   1.0  2.0   3.0
           price        2.0  3.0   4.0
           quantity    18.0  6.0   7.0
2012-07-17              NaN  NaN   NaN
           investment   1.0  2.0   3.0
           price        0.0  1.0   4.0
           quantity     5.0  1.0   0.0
```

```
#lexsorted Multiindex           
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

#select data and remove last level, because:
#1. need shift
#2. easier working
idx = pd.IndexSlice
p = df.loc[idx[:,'price'],:]
p.index = p.index.droplevel(-1)
q = df.loc[idx[:,'quantity'],:]
q.index = q.index.droplevel(-1)
print (p)
            ABC  DEF  GHI
Date                     
2012-07-17  0.0  1.0  4.0
2012-07-18  2.0  3.0  4.0
2012-07-19  5.0  8.0  1.0

print (q)
             ABC  DEF  GHI
Date                      
2012-07-17   5.0  1.0  0.0
2012-07-18  18.0  6.0  7.0
2012-07-19  12.0  9.0  8.0
```

```
print (p * q)
             ABC   DEF   GHI
Date                        
2012-07-17   0.0   1.0   0.0
2012-07-18  36.0  18.0  28.0
2012-07-19  60.0  72.0   8.0

print ((p * q).sum(axis=1).to_frame().rename(columns={0:'col1'}))
             col1
Date             
2012-07-17    1.0
2012-07-18   82.0
2012-07-19  140.0
```

```
#shift row with -1, because lexsorted df
print (p.shift(-1, freq='D') * q)
             ABC   DEF  GHI
Date                       
2012-07-16   NaN   NaN  NaN
2012-07-17  10.0   3.0  0.0
2012-07-18  90.0  48.0  7.0
2012-07-19   NaN   NaN  NaN

print ((p.shift(-1, freq='D') * q).sum(axis=1).to_frame().rename(columns={0:'col2'}))
             col2
Date             
2012-07-16    0.0
2012-07-17   13.0
2012-07-18  145.0
2012-07-19    0.0
```

Comment: thnks for the hard work always!! iam going to go thru it and comment afterwards.. i guess i can always copy col2 to my original pd.Series(XN) after right? cuz i actually need to keep the inner level..

Comment: ;) I ask about desired output - you need new column to `DataFrame` ? If yes, what is index of this new column? `datetime` and `investment` ?

Comment: ohhh .yes i need a new column in the `Dataframe` the index for the new column would have the value on `Investment`. thnk you! :)

Comment: I create another solution, because it is completely different.

Comment: I have email in my profile ;) But I dont know if i have time for it, but you can send me email.

Comment: oh I see ok nice. i will reach out.thnks

Comment: -nice! it prints nicely in the console, but for some reason when i save it to csv it does not show the new column.. -any insight?